# django documentation locally setting up

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I was trying to setup django . I do have Django-1.1-alpha-1. I was trying to make the documentation which is located at Django-1.1-alpha-1/doc using make utility.

But I am getting some error saying

```
> C:\django\Django-1.1-alpha-1\docs>C:\cygwin\bin\make.exe html

mkdir -p _build/html _build/doctrees
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
make: sphinx-build: Command not found
make: *** [html] Error 127
```

Do anybody knows how to solve this issue and make a html documentation

Thanks
J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

```
$ easy_install -U Sphinx
```

Comment: In my setup with Django 1.0.2 running on Windows I had to apply this patch http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/11162#file0 before Sphinx would work. Something with the docs makefile not being compatible with a newer version of Sphinx yet. It is probably fixed in 1.1